# Run a Python script in UIPath

Tags: python, python-3.x, uipath, uipath-orchestrator

I am trying to run a python script in UIPath Orchestrator. I am dragging a python scope and inside it a Run Python Script activity.

Under Python Scope path I am setting the path which i get after using the command where python in cmd. And setting the target as x64 for 64bit. Added the working directory as current UIPath project.
Under run python script activity I entered the script location...

After running the flow, I do not see any result. The flow does not enter the Python scope activity (added a log message to verify this. Never gets this log).

Can anyone help me with this?

Tried to change the path after viewing various answers on the net. Nothing works... Current python version is 3.9

Comment: Add an image here and the log messages.

Comment: This question might be better suited for the UiPath forums, since it's very specific to your situation. If you post there, make sure to should provide the python file you're using and the xaml file so that people can help you debug.